# Stride and Width in image processing

Tags: c#, image-processing, pixel, bitmapimage, bitmapdata

I HAVE A 1bpp image that needs to be read.

I came across the following logic. but I am not sure what it is trying to do.

```
     int value = (imagebmd.Width + 15) >> 3;       
     byte* row = (byte*)imagebmd.Scan0;
```

I don't understand what value is stored in columns and row variables.

Comment: C# + byte * don't mix?

Answer (score 0):

```
int columns = (imagebmd.Width + 7) >> 3;
```

This is **byte** length of image line. It is equivalent of rounding up

```
columns = Ceil(bitwidth / 8)
```

row is pointer to image data start address.